# Como somar os valores de cada elemento de 2 listas com List Comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho 2 listas e quero somar o elemento de cada posição da lista a com o elemento da mesma posição na lista b, só que utilizando `<b>List Comprehension </b>`

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
```

Com map ficaria assim:

```
list(map(lambda x,y: x+y, a, b))

Out: [6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Gostaria de saber como faço o correspondente a isso utilizando `List Comprehension`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um List Comprehension obtendo o tamanho de uma das listas para inserir em um `for..range` e depois retornar a soma do elemento de posição `i` das listas `a` e `b`. Veja o código abaixo:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]

r = [a[i] + b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

É claro que para isso funcionar, ambas as listas precisam ter a mesma quantidade de elementos ou senão será gerado um `IndexError`. Para contornar esse problema, podemos verificar qual o tamanho máximo que podemos percorrer, dessa forma:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]

limit = len(min(a, b)) # Obtém o tamanho da menor lista
r = [a[i] + b[i] for i in range(limit)]
```

Se você não quiser ter o trabalho de fazer verificação, você pode utilizar um `zip()` para juntar cada elemento das listas e depois utilizar a função `sum()` para somar os elementos retornados. Exemplo:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]

r = [sum(values) for values in zip(a, b)]
```